# Multiplicative linear functionals on B(H)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

I can prove that there are no non- zero multiplicative linear functionals on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

It is said that if dim $H > 1$. Since $B(H)$ contains an embedded copy of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$, such a functional would have to restrict to a multiplicative linear functional on $M_2(\mathbb{C})$, which doesn’t exist.Hence $B(H)$ has non non- zero multiplicative linear functionals.

Can anyone tell how $B(H)$ contains an embedded copy of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$,?

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2723202/1104384

Answer (score 1):

The answer linked by Bruno is not too clear, in my opinion.

Here are two easy ways of doing it. Let $\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis (I'll assume countable for notational simplicity, but there is no real need).

A key notion to talk about this stuff is that of *matrix units*. The matrix units coming from the orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ are the operators $E_{kj}$ given by
$$
E_{kj}\,z=\langle z,e_j\rangle\,e_k. 
$$
They satisfy
$$
E_{kj}E_{ab}=\delta_{j,a}\,E_{kb}. 
$$

1. If you don't care about the embedding being unital, you can consider the "upper left corner":
   $$M=\big\{T\in B(H): \ker T=\ker T^*=\{e_1,e_2\}^\perp\big\}.
   $$
   You also have $M=PB(H)P$, where $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{span}\{e_1,e_2\}$.
2. If you want the embedding to be unital, you can take $p=\sum_kE_{2k-1,2k-1}$ and $q=\sum_kE_{2k,2k}$. Then $p,q$ are orthogonal projetions with $p+q=1$. If we take $v=\sum_k E_{2k-1,2k}$, then $v$ is a partial isometry with $v^*v=p$, $vv^*=q$. You can now identify $N=\operatorname{span}\{p,q,v,v^*\}$ with $M_2(\mathbb C)$ (as a $*$-isomorphism) by mapping
   $$
   p\longmapsto e_{11},\qquad v\longmapsto e_{12},\qquad v^*\longmapsto e_{21},\qquad q\longmapsto e_{22}. 
   $$